# VPN connection Ubuntu 16.04 issues

Tags: networking, vpn, remmina

I work from home and login remotely to work. This has just changed to a VPN and I'm having issues. I'm able through network manager to setup the VPN which successfully connects, however then what? I don't know how to actually login and see my screen from work. I've tried the excellent Remmina but it is not connecting. IT have given me 'Endpoint 1.11.111.11' (not those numbers) and told me 'Security options:- use EAP with 'Microsoft: Secured password (EAP-MSCHAP v2) (encryption enabled)'. There is probably something I need to install to actually see my work screen and not just the 'connection successful message' at the top? Thank you.

Comment: You try to connect on some resource in office, some server or you try to connect to you pc in office? if you try to connect you pc in office, do you setup some rdesktop, vmc, teamviewer, ssh .... on that pc? Can you ping your pc in office? "Endpoint" and "EAP" is param for connection, but you do not have problem with connection.

Comment: Thanks, we have a terminal services setup on Windows. When in the office we have to connect via Microsoft remote desktop to work on the terminal server. When out of the office a VPN system applies. I'm trying to find out if I have to have an equivalent of Microsoft remote desktop to connect over a VPN, or if Remmina can do it but I'm not configuring it correctly.

Comment: You can use `rdesktop`. Connect to `vpn` then simple try to access your server with `rdesktop` To install `rdesktop use command `sudo apt-get install rdesktop` After instlation run `rdesktop ip_of_your_server`

Comment: Thanks, it comes up with Autoselected keyboard map en-gb however the desktop over VPN does not appear on the screen, it just stops there. It seems as though the connection is established but I cannot actually see the windows login screen.

Comment: I'm now trying to connect via Remmina whilst I'm in the VPN session. However it is coming up with timeout errors. I don't think I've configured this right.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't been given the right server address, I put the right one it in and it connects. Thanks for the help!